# Toolbar layout doesn't match parent width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I've read several similar topics, but still haven't found an answer for this issue. I have a custom layout for a toolbar:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#99000000">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_transparent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/MyToolbar">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's my code in activity:

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_transparent);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

My toolbar still has left and right padding and doesn't fill parent width. I've tried various solutions. What's wrong with my code? 
The matter is that i need my toolbar to be semi transparent. That's why i use this line in a layout android:background="#99000000". I apply it to the whole layout and my toolbar becomes semi transparent, but it doesn't fill parent in width. But if i apply android:background="#99000000" this line not to the whole layout, but to my toolbar widget in a layout it fills parent correctly, but looses transparency. Can this help?

Comment: What is inside your theme MyToolbar?

Comment: @Yupi <style name="MyToolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/back_arrow</item>
    </style>

Comment: You could try manually setting the padding to be zero just in case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RelativeLayout is not matching parent width inside a ToolBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54797519/relativelayout-is-not-matching-parent-width-inside-a-toolbar)

Answer (score 1):

If padding is the problem, you can try setting the `contentInset` attributes:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#attr_android:contentInsetStart

Answer (score 1):

Try this layout:

for semi Transperant `toolbar`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/general_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#99000000">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thank's for an answer, but the problem remained unsolved:(

Comment: left and right padding remained unchanged. My layout is also semi transparent, but i can't deal with padding(