# RelativeLayout is not matching parent width inside a ToolBar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-relativelayout

So I have a customized toolbar on my home screen, and within this toolbar is a `RelativeLayout`. I have the `layout width` set to `match_parent` and the parent of the relative layout is just the width of the screen.

For some reason, it does not fit the width of the screen because the left edge is some distance away from the edge of the screen. I am not sure why this is but it is making positioning within the `RelativeLayout` a bit more difficult.

This is my `.xml`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/products_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:titleTextColor="#000000">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topRL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="72sp"
            android:layout_height="37sp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="137dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="159dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/veganstyle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="BL"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#efefef"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And this is a screenshot showing what I am talking about.

[image]

As you can see, the blue box surrounding the `RelativeLayout` is not at the edge of the screen, nor will it let me bring it to the edge.

Neither the `RelativeLayout` or its parent have any padding or margins, so I am confused why this is an issue and how I can solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the following attribute in your `ToolBar`

```
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

Hence your layout should be something like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/products_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:titleTextColor="#000000">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topRL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="72sp"
            android:layout_height="37sp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="BL"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#efefef"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here is this from the [developer's documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#attr_android:contentInsetStart).